# What is the standard protocol for pools/miners?

Tags: mining-pools, json-rpc, getwork, stratum, getblocktemplate

The Bitcoin client protocol is well documented in the Bitcoin Wiki, but I can't find much on the protocol used by pools and miners. Is it described anywhere?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When there were no pools, all of the first mining clients interfaced directly with Bitcoin. They connected to Bitcoin's JSON-RPC interface and used the *getwork* RPC method to get the required work. Getting work from a pool is the same as getting work from Bitcoin. The client connects to the pool over HTTP, often using the same HTTP authentication that Bitcoin's JSON-RPC interface uses; the client sends a JSON-RPC *getwork* message; and the pool sends back a JSON-RPC *getwork* response.

Many pools nowadays support some extensions to the *getwork* protocol that Bitcoin does not.

See:
https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Getwork

Comment: Since this answer was written there are two new protocols; Stratum and gbt (getblocktemplate). Stratum seems the most popular, and getwork is being phased out by most clients and servers.