# Software to connect to Bitcoin, and the method I need to invoke to try mining a bitcoin using a hash I have generated?

Tags: miner-configuration, solo-mining, mining-software

I'm looking to try out solo mining, I know it as a very low return rate but I want to try it out anyway...

I'm looking for a simple client software to connect into the bitcoin network.
Which instruction would I invoke on this software in order to try out a hash I have generated?
i.e. is there something like tryHash(int hash) that returns a Bitcoin if successful?

Comment: CPU mining, GPU mining or ASIC mining?  Pool or solo?

Comment: I have my own custom way of generating hashes, lets just say I have a box that outputs a hash, I want to send that hash to the bitcoin network, the box will be a custom piece of electronics.

Comment: Sounds intriguing!!!

Comment: Did you see this question? http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/16940/what-are-asic-miners-actullay-doing

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you do need to connect to a mining pool---which you can provide yourself by running the bitcoin client if it indeed has to be solo mining for you. Note that from your question it is obvious you do not understand the implication: Solo mining can only get you at least a block reward (or nothing), so currently, you can never get just a single Bitcoin, you have to accept at least 25 in solo mining. Only by joining a mining pool can you get smaller rewards for less difficult-to-find hashes.

Anyways, connecting can be as simple as doing a RPC call. With this, I guess I can refer you on to [the bitcoin.stackexchange question "What is the standard protocol for pools/miners?"](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/1323/what-is-the-standard-protocol-for-pools-miners).

Here's the summary, slightly updated from the linked question:

1. The legacy bitcoin RPC call you could use is [getwork](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Getwork). You can probably find a mining pool that supports it (but I haven't checked that). One minimalistic sample implementation, [Minimal-Bitcoin-Miner on github](https://github.com/lithander/Minimal-Bitcoin-Miner), can be found linked to and with what you call the "tryHash" bit discussed in the question linked to by RentFree in a comment to your question.
2. The newer [getblocktemplate](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Getblocktemplate) may work better for you. Many mining pools seem to support it.
3. If you want to work in a specific pool, check if they are inventing their own protocol, just in case that suits you even better. [Slush's protocol](http://mining.bitcoin.cz/stratum-mining) is one example.

Good luck and let us know when (if ever) you can unveil your hash-solving black box!
If it promises to work well enough to support paid help, may I apply, having expertise spanning pretty much anything that might be relevant (quantum physics, electronics, programming, mathematics)?

Comment: Cheers for the answer! What would be the second greatest bottle in the mining process? after the hash generation of course.

Comment: Also where abouts are you based?

Comment: 1. Could you clarify what you mean by 2nd biggest bottle(neck, I presume)? Even without profiling, I feel confident in saying >99% of computing time of just about any miner goes into hash calculation. There is no other bottleneck worth mentioning.

2. Europe. But I don't currently run an established business anywhere and am willing to move anywhere. Where are you based?